# When i write a task "php symfony .." I only get the first lines of config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php

Tags: symfony1

I have done a "svn co" for a repository that contains a symfony app.

Then i went to the root of the project and when i write a task "php
symfony .." I only get the first lines of config/
ProjectConfiguration.class.php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('session.save_handler','files');
ini_set('safe_mode','Off');
ini_set('register_globals','Off');
ini_set('memory_limit','128M');

/*
 * This file is part of the symfony package.
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien.potenc...@symfony-project.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the
LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/
ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
include(sfCoreAutoload::getInstance()->getBaseDir().'/command/
cli.php');
```

and the prompt again.

Anyone knows?

sf 1.4

Javier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
php symfony -V
```

You should get the version number.  If you do not, your symfony installation might be corrupted.

Ensure your server specifications meet the minimum requirements to run symfony.  You must ensure you have php 5.3+ installed properly.

If you are still sure everything should be working, try to elaborate your question a little more.

Answer (score 0):

If the output is the one you described, it seems the php open tags are missing

In that case, php would just output the content of the file. Please check if the tags are present.